# Custom aggregation of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have below dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3], 'B' : ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 'C' : ['XX', 'YY', 'ZZ'], 'D' : [1,1,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1+1,2+1,3+1], 'B' : ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 'C' : ['XX', 'YY', 'ZZ'], 'D' : [2,2,2]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1+3,2+3,3+3], 'B' : ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 'C' : ['XX', 'YY', 'ZZ'], 'D' : [3,3,3]})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis = 0, ignore_index = True)
```

Now I want to create an aggregated dataframe from `df`, based on the distinct values in the column `'D'`. The aggregation will be based on the numerical column `'A'` with below rule :

For matching values of columns `'B'` and `'C'`, final value of column `'A'` will be

```
0.4 * 1 + 0.5 * 2 + 0.5 * 4, 0.4 * 2 + 0.5 * 3 + 0.5 * 5, and 0.4 * 3 + 0.5 * 4 + 0.5 * 6
```

Here, the numbers `0.4, 0.5, and 0.5` are fixed and can be treated as weights.

My final dataframe shall look like

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0.4 * 1 + 0.5 * 2 + 0.5 * 4,0.4 * 2 + 0.5 * 3 + 0.5 * 5,0.4 * 3 + 0.5 * 4 + 0.5 * 6], 'B' : ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 'C' : ['XX', 'YY', 'ZZ'], 'D' : ['Aggregated', 'Aggregated', 'Aggregated']})
     A  B   C           D
0  3.4  X  XX  Aggregated
1  4.8  Y  YY  Aggregated
2  6.2  Z  ZZ  Aggregated
```

I have many subgroups in my actual dataframe and therefore looking for some automated way to achieve the same.

Is there any method/function available to achieve the same?

Comment: it is hard to understand what your goal is. Could you please add a desired output? That would make it a lot easier. If I understand the weights and its values correctly, you want to groupby column C and not column D?

Comment: @Rabinzel Hi, I have modified my original post to include my desired dataframe

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but the values per distinct `D`-value seem to be incorrect. For `D == 1`. you are applying the weights to `[1,2,4]`, but the associated `A`-values are `[1,2,3]`; also for `D == 2`, you use `[2,3,5]` instead of `[2,3,4]` and finally, for `D == 3`, you use: `[3,4,6]` instead of `[4,5,6]`. Please clarify.

Comment: @ouroboros1 I was confused aswell. The described goal doesn't fit to the numbers. I think he wants to groupby column C (or B, looks like it doesn't matter) and then calculate the weights on each group of A. I don't know what role column D has here.

Comment: @ouroboros1 Weight to be applied w.r.t. the blocks i.e. distinct values of `D`, not on elements within a block. For example, please consider the last value of my `final dataframe` which is `0.4 * 3 + 0.5 * 4 + 0.5 * 6`. Here `3` comes from the row `[3,  Z,  ZZ,  1]`, `4` comes from `[4,  Z,  ZZ,  2]` and `6` comes from `[6,  Z,  ZZ,  3]`

Comment: Seems like you indeed want to groupby `C` (or `B`; doesn't matter here). Otherwise, the logic might be: pick *first* `1, 2, 3` in `D`, then *second*, etc. That would in this example of course lead to the same answer as grouping by `C` (or `B`).  But you mention you care about "matching values of columns `B` and `C`", which should hardly matter in this case. If the answer by @Rabinzel is correct, please update the question to reflect the need for *that / such an answer*. As is, that answer is just a way to get to your desired output in some (correct) way. It's not following your "logic".

Comment: I think I follow the logic of "matching values of columns 'B' and 'C', final value of column 'A' will be" with its weight. The input and the desired output indicate that he wants to do exactly that. I just still don't know why D is mentioned again. I see no use for it in that task. @BrianSmith please see my answer and check if it fits your goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired output you could do something like this:

```py
#lambda also possible but this looks a bit cleaner
def weights(grp):
    val1,val2,val3 = grp
    return 0.4*val1 + 0.5*val2 + 0.5*val3

# the aggregations on B and D are just examples. You can change that to whatever you like
df.groupby('C').agg({'A':weights, 'B':'first', 'D':lambda x: 'aggregated'}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    C    A  B           D
0  XX  3.4  X  aggregated
1  YY  4.8  Y  aggregated
2  ZZ  6.2  Z  aggregated
```